# Simpler way to look up an NSDictionary key?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, performance, optimization, dictionary

In a program I am working on I am using a C array of chars (it is potentially a very large array, so I do not want to use an NSArray). Each one is storing a value that corresponds to a particular status.

So that I can store some information about each status, I am using an NSDictionary. Each of the keys correspond to the possible status values. For each key, the value is a sub-dictionary that contains information I need corresponding to the status value.

Currently I am doing the following whenever I want to extract information from the NSDictionary:

```
for(i=0; i<arrayLen; i++) {

NSString *lookupKey1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", array[i]];
int stateInfo1 = [[[statesDict objectForKey:lookupKey1] 
                                objectForKey:@"infoKey1"] intValue];
[lookupKey1 release];


NSString *lookupKey2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", array[i]];
int stateInfo2 = [[[statesDict objectForKey:lookupKey2] 
                                objectForKey:@"infoKey2"] intValue];
[lookupKey2 release];


// Now do something with the values just obtained...

}
```

This works just fine, but what I don't like about having to do this is that I am having to allocate an NSString, just to look up a key. It feels like I am performing unnecessary operations. This is a particular concern to me since I am iterating through a large array and I don't want to be slowing it down by doing it in this way unless I absolutely have to.

When I try to simply pass the char in as I originally hoped I could to:

```
char stateInfo = [[[statesDict objectForKey:array[i]] 
                                objectForKey:@"infoKey"] charValue];
```

The compiler gives the warning "Passing argument 1 of objectForKey: makes pointer from integer without a cast", and the debugger throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

I have also tried passing in a formatted string literal:

```
char stateInfo = [[[statesDict objectForKey:(@"%i", array[i])] 
                                objectForKey:@"infoKey"] charValue];
```

This throws up exactly the same error. Does anybody know if there is a more efficient way to do what I am trying to do, or is the way I described in the first snippet the 'correct' way to go about what I am trying to do?

Comment: how big is the array? Also note that "string literals" are also instances of `NSString`

Comment: It varies massively as it is user specified, but I have been working with arrays of up to 10000+ elements. Which is why the thought of an NSArray scares me.. All of those objects cant be good for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
char stateInfo = [[[statesDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", array[i]] 
                                objectForKey:@"infoKey"] charValue];
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler than what I was doing in terms of coding, would this also work out computationally 'cheaper' too do you think? My worry with what I was doing before was creating and releasing potentially thousands of strings would take its toll on the processor!

Comment: @tom1990 I do this with thousands and it works great. You might want to try it and see how it reacts with your data, but for me it works good.

Comment: I had a go at implementing it in this way, it works fine and the code looks neater too. I have one question though relating to memory management. If I am doing it this way do I need to have an autorelease pool in place? I don't have one currently and The static analyser is giving me no warnings.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do to simplify your access:

- Use `NSNumber` instead of `NSString` as keys of your `NSDictionary`
- Use autoreleased keys to avoid calls of `release`

This would simplify your code a little:

```
int stateInfo2 = [[[statesDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:array[i]]] 
                            objectForKey:@"infoKey2"] intValue];
```

If the number of code is relatively small, there is a good chance that there would be no allocation of `NSNumber` in the current implementation: according to [this link](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-205556.html), `[NSNumber numberWithInt:...]` will return the same object for low values of the integer.

**EDIT :** Since property lists do not support keys of type other than `NSString`, you need to convert the dictionary obtained from plist to a dictionary with `NSNumber` keys like this:

```
NSDictionary *fromPlist = ... // This is your original dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *target = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[fromPlist enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    [target setObject:obj forKey:[key intValue]];
}];
```

Comment: I didn't think to make use of the NSNumber object instead, thanks for that point. Since I have always used strings before that was probably a habit, but all of the keys I am using are numbers so that does indeed simplify the access.

Comment: Hi, I have just had a go at implementing my code by using the [NSNumber numberWithInt:] method, but for some reason it returns (null) when I try and access the dictionary? Is there something I need to do to set up my dictionary to use NSNumber keys instead? I am loading the dictionary from a plist, and cannot find a way to change the key type in the plist editor?

Comment: @tom1990 plists do not support keys of type other than `NSString`. Please see my edit to see how to fix it.

Comment: I see, thanks for that update! That makes sense, I was wondering why I could not find the option in the plist editor!

Answer (score 2):

NSDictionary* can only take objects as keys and values. When you pass it a char, it's casting it to a pointer.

@dasblinkenlight makes a good suggestion, although I guess you're slightly at the mercy of when the frameworks decide to give you a shared NSNumber instance, which could vary between OS releases.

Another option would be to rename your source file so that the extension is .mm and use a c++ std::map, which handles this sort of thing trivially.

```
#import <map>

@implementation MyClass {
  std::map<char, int> statesMap;

...

int stateInfo1 = statesMap[i];
```

**That all said, I'd be worried that you're worrying unecessarily about this:**

> All these objects can't be good for performance

Even with an array with 10,000 elements, the memory overhead of using unique object keys is going to be about 80k. The equivalent of a couple of icons. Unless you're making hundreds of these, it's unlikely to cause memory issues. Performance-wise, go off data from the profiling tools, not assumptions. The bottlenecks are unlikely to be in the places you expect them to be in.

Comment: You make a very good point! I am worrying about the amount of objects too much. My programming experience is mainly from using pure C and OOP is a bit of a new thing to me, so im still trying to get my head around some of the concepts. I think my main problem with using objects was that I was feeling that I was having to add additional steps in my code which could slow it down, like converting the CArray values into something that can be used to look up the dictionary.

Comment: Handling primitive types is one of the uglier bits of Objective-C in my experience. You either have to box them into objects manually, or not use the OO stuff for them. Always worth remembering C and C++ can both be used in an obj-c source file though, so the second option isn't always so bad.